# Missing rows when merging

Tags: excel, join, merge, powerpivot, powerquery

I am working with Excel 2010, Power Query, and PowerPivot.

I have a query named Database that consists of 60+ merged tables containing a total of 2m+ rows. I also have a separate query that consists of two columns PrimaryKey3 and Members (a count of members per month). The entries in PrimaryKey3 are unique, consisting of ID-MMM-YY.

Both queries have PrimaryKey3 in common, however in Database there can be multiple rows with the same PrimaryKey3.

In order to match a member amount to each row in Database, I tried a Left Outer join. There were no errors, but when I try to upload to PowerPivot it says there are only 169K rows. I then tried Full Outer join and Inner Join, and received an error "could not convert value to number," coming from a column already formatted as a text in Database. This column contains numbers and numbers proceeding with a letter: 1234, A234. Every non-blank row has a PrimaryKey3. Why is it trying to reformat my columns/ how do I get around that?

Should I be using a different type of join, or is there another way besides merging to do this?

Hope this makes sense, thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded both queries to PowerPivot, and created a relationship through PrimaryKey3. I then created a new column in Database with =Related(Enrollment[Members]).